# How to process signals/idle inside a QThread?

Tags: qt, qthread, qt-signals, qtcore

I have created a simple threaded network server. The main.cpp calls app.exec() to idle, and the thread fires off as expected once I establish a connection.

In the thread's run() function, I hookup a signal from readyRead to a slot called readCommand:

```
connect(tcpSocketPtr, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readCommand()) );
```

and I have defined the readCommand in the .h file for the class, as a "private slot" - since it is only called from within the class. Hope that's right.

after the connect above, the run() function returns. There is no app.exec() call or anything.  Could that be the problem? Do I have to call some function to cause the thread to listen for signals?

When I send text to the port the readCommand function never fires...and I have no idea how to debug this..suggestions?

Comment: You need to call `QThread::exec()` inside the body of `run()` to start the thread's event loop.  Otherwise, the thread will quit upon reaching the end of `run()`.

Comment: @Michelle: what is the reason why you have not selected an answer? What is missing from the reply?

Comment: Is it still unresolved more than one year later??

Comment: It's resolved but the only answer with an accept check is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

> and I have defined the readCommand in the .h file for the class, as a
>   "private slot" - since it is only called from within the class. Hope
>   that's right.

Yes, that looks correct.

However, you should use `int QThread::exec() [protected]` inside the `void QThread::run() [virtual protected]` method to start the thread execution as opposed to returning almost instantly.